# Optimistic concurrency for Azure Storage blob always throws HTTP 412

Tags: .net, azure

In order to implement optimistic concurrency for an Azure Storage blob I am constructing an **If-Match AccessCondition** based on the ETag value from the properties of a blob.

If another process has updated the blob, the blob service should return an HTTP 412 (Precondition Failed) status message. However, the service is **always** returning this 412 status.

For this example I've looked up the ETag value manually using Storage Explorer.

A minimal snippet to reproduce the problem is:

```cs
var storage = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

var blobClient = storage.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("foo");

var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("foo/1");

await blob.UploadTextAsync(
          "test", 
           Encoding.UTF8,
           AccessCondition.GenerateIfMatchCondition("\"0x1A52537587A1234\""),
           new BlobRequestOptions(),
           null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I accidentally used the wrong `blobName`:

```
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("foo/1");
```

That should be:

```
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("1");
```

or else the ETag check will correctly fail since there is no blob with the name `foo/1`.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload blob with specific `ETAG` value, it will work for the first time. However, when you secondly upload blob with same `ETAG` it will throw 412 error. Because once you operate the blob, its `ETAG` will update.

**Optimistic concurrency for blobs and containers**

A user performing an update on such an object can send in the original `ETag` along with a conditional header to ensure that an update will only occur if a certain condition has been met – in this case the condition is an `If-Match` header which requires the Storage Service to ensure the value of the `ETag` specified in the update request is the same as that stored in the Storage Service.

```
// Retrieve Etag from the response of an earlier UploadText blob operation.
string orignalETag = blockBlob.Properties.ETag;
// This code simulates an update by a third party.
string helloText = "Blob updated by a third party.";
// No etag, provided so orignal blob is overwritten (thus generating a new etag)
blockBlob.UploadText(helloText);
Console.WriteLine("Blob updated. Updated ETag = {0}", blockBlob.Properties.ETag);
// Now try to update the blob using the orignal ETag provided when the blob was created
try
{
     Console.WriteLine("Trying to update blob using orignal etag to generate if-match access condition");
     blockBlob.UploadText(helloText,accessCondition:
     AccessCondition.GenerateIfMatchCondition(orignalETag));
}
catch (StorageException ex)
{
     if (ex.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Precondition failure as expected. Blob's orignal etag no longer matches");
     }
}
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-concurrency-in-microsoft-azure-storage-2/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't answer my question. I'm passing the original ETag along with the If-Match condition. But even though the blog has not been updated by third party, the operation will *always* throw 412.

Comment: That's strange. I test your code with original ETAG, and it works well.